# Fixing background issue on jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the website where I have the issue: http://florin-pop.com/work/

The body has the following CSS:

```
body {
        height:100%;
        font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
       background-image: url("bg.jpg");
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: left top;
       color: #333;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
```

As you can see the bg size is cover, but this is causing me a little problem when the users navigate on the portfolio fiters (e.g. ALL, PSD->HTML/CSS, Animated ...) because the height of the container is changing and also the background image, which makes it look a little weird.

How can I have the cover property (the responsiveness) but negate the background changing while the animation takes place?

I've tried changing from `cover` to `100%` but this is also not right because it won't cover the whole page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `background-attachment` to `fixed`

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would set the min-height of the pictrue to the actual height of it.

```
body 
{
       min-height: 1200px;
       height:100%;
       font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
       background-image: url("bg.jpg");
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: left top;
       color: #333;
       overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you applying overflow hidden on the body? How are users supposed to scroll down?

You could do the following:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #333;
  /* overflow: hidden; */      
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Get a large image, one larger than the average browser (5000x2500 for example), and set the background-attachment to fixed. This will make the background stay the same on every page, and not move when scrolling.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want large image like that. It will be like 5-10mb. Also, I need a small version image for mobile and tablet.

Comment: Firstly, use tinypng.com to compress images without loosing noticeable quality. Secondly, you could use a bit of jQuery to load the background image, and adjust which one it loads depending on the viewport. So you could load a smaller image on smaller screens etc.